# How to Remove multiple root element in JSON?

Tags: json, apigee

```
"{
    "LEINumber": "335800QRNLKAHGA1BL68",
    "LegalName": "METROPOLITAN CLEARING CORPORATION OF INDIA LIMITED",
    "NextRenewalDate": "04-03-2022 00:00:00 +05:30",
    "LegalForm": "Public Limited Companies",
    "RegistrationStatus": "ISSUED"
}"
```

In above Json Packet i want to remove the "" in JSON. So after removing the "" i want the data in below format.

```
{
    "LEINumber": "335800QRNLKAHGA1BL68",
    "LegalName": "METROPOLITAN CLEARING CORPORATION OF INDIA LIMITED",
    "NextRenewalDate": "04-03-2022 00:00:00 +05:30",
    "LegalForm": "Public Limited Companies",
    "RegistrationStatus": "ISSUED"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for this simple solution is to print the data not in " " in apigee. If you use double inverted commas it will print the data with commas but if you print the data without double inverted commas it will not print in commas as shown below.

```
{
    "LEINumber": "335800QRNLKAHGA1BL68",
    "LegalName": "METROPOLITAN CLEARING CORPORATION OF INDIA LIMITED",
    "NextRenewalDate": "04-03-2022 00:00:00 +05:30",
    "LegalForm": "Public Limited Companies",
    "RegistrationStatus": "ISSUED"
}
```